# How to create popup image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Since I am new to javascript, I cannot figure out how to make popup image slider. Images should not be displayed on original html page, only in a popup window. Could someone outline steps I should follow as a guide in order to achieve this effect? Is it complicated for a novice?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a "Code it for me" site, We will try help you solve your problems regarding the code you are using.

Comment: You basically want a pop-up that contains the image/s, right?

Comment: follow Carousel. : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: kdyz: yes, that is right.

Comment: Carsten Løvbo Andersen: I did not mean anyone should code for me. Just outline steps like: create overlay div, then create this and so on... I basically did not get past overlay div lol.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do, just need to edit/add images and text. Hope this helps!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/575/technics/3" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/575/technics/3" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you use the [Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Basically, you need two things: one popup box and a carousel in it.

for the popup:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

for the carousel inside it:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

It's the easiest and most scalable method. Hope it helps you.